# Writing a file in document directory in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

hi i want write a some audio file into Document directory, at first i had created the folder using below code , the folder created properly ..

```
func createfolder(throwerror: AnyObject)  {

    let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = Directorypath[0]
    let finalPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Audio")
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(finalPath, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
        do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(finalPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil);
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error.localizedDescription",error.localizedDescription);
            exceptionobj.filedirectoryexecption(.isfoldercreated, controller: throwerror as! UIViewController)
        }
    }else{print("Folder Exist");}
}
```

then the i want write audio file using below code

```
func WritefileintoDirectory(viewcontroller: AnyObject,filedata:NSData?,filetype :Filetype,filename : String,Rootfolder : Filetype){

        var tempfilename = "/";
        tempfilename += filename  
        switch filetype {
        case .Image:
            tempfilename += ".png"
        case .Audio:
            tempfilename += ".m4a"
        }
        let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = Directorypath[0]
        let directorypath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(String(Rootfolder));
        let finalPath = directorypath + tempfilename;
        print("finalPath",finalPath);
        if filedata != nil{
            let Status =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(finalPath, contents: filedata, attributes: nil);
            if !Status {
              exceptionobj.filedirectoryexecption(.isfilewritten, controller: viewcontroller as! UIViewController)
            }
        }
    }
```

above code i will pass the file name like "httpstoragegoogleapiscommememtobackend1321appspotcomaudiosL2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfZXVyb3BlL2Jsb2JzL0FFbkIyVXBjNlgtbUk5aGxzcWQzTjg2Rmw5bmlQd05vbXRzYzdzaVJUN1RUTFV4UlFHcUhKR1V0UHJNR0k3cjZpOURPTlZ4d0s4V3ZEbFVrbFlicDQ0WUhaanA2d0s1T0tMNmFKOWJVUnNvY3BIenFCZDNlb0VrLk96N0RYd2pVcE5oTnhRSHg" but the file could't be written in directory . if i hardcoded the file name like "audiofile1" it is working perfectly..

Kindly provide me what is issue is to here ...

Comment: Checking for errors might help...